# Ruby on Rails Sessions for new users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, session-cookies

We have some sharing elements of our application where we embed logging IDs into the URL's that we share out. When a user clicks that URL, we add a record to our database so we can hopefully follow them throughout the registration process. We've found that if you reset your browser and go to the link the first time, there is no session info from the controller. However, all subsequent requests then have the session. It's almost like it's getting created after the first request.

We attempted to log it via ajax on the view, but this is cumbersome in all the places we want.

Anyone know what sessions wouldn't be available in the controller on first access for a new uesr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have code in the wrong order. You must have the session creation before any logic can my applied to it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It appears that setting a session value then forces the creation of the cookie. If you don't do that, since they're lazily loaded, the cookie is not yet created and thus not available to the code in the controller.